# Powershell any way to hide yes and no popup while adding registry

Tags: powershell

I am trying to Change Desktop wallpaper using **Power shell** by adding registry

```
reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\control panel\desktop" /v wallpaper /t REG_SZ /d "" /f
reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\control panel\desktop" /v wallpaper /t REG_SZ /d C:\Users\ov3\Desktop\pic\wall.jpg /f
reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\control panel\desktop" /v WallpaperStyle /t REG_SZ /d 2 /f
RUNDLL32.EXE user32.dll,UpdatePerUserSystemParameters
```

after adding these keys wallpaper changed successfully now I want to again change the wallpaper but receiving **Yes** and **No** confirmation message

```
PS C:\Users\ov3> reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\control panel\desktop" /v wallpaper /t REG_SZ /d "" /f
Value wallpaper exists, overwrite(Yes/No)? yes
```

I am using **/f** to force overwrite but still receiving this message **Value wallpaper exists, overwrite(Yes/No)** is there any way to Hide this?

Comment: This works for me: `reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\control panel\desktop" /v wallpaper /t REG_SZ /d '""' /f` (single quotes around double quotes)

Comment: A [comment on this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/1995#issuecomment-742568351) mentions this specific case, so hopefully it will be fixed in the future.

Comment: btw, the PowerShell way would be `Set-ItemProperty 'hkcu:\control panel\desktop' wallpaper ''` -- no special quoting necessary and even less verbose than the 'reg.exe' call.

Comment: can you tell me where z the problem `WshShell.Run("reg add 'HKEY_CURRENT_USER\control panel\desktop\' /v wallpaper /t REG_SZ /d '""' /f",0);`

Error: Expected ')'

Comment: Enclose the full command in double quotes and not just untill /f. I agree with Zett42 though, this is not the powershell way to do it. See his suggestion with `Set-ItemProperty`.